# Reproducing a sketch of a Phased Array Antenna with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reproduce the following sketch:

[image]

So far, I have created this:

[image]

using the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,0);
\draw (3,0.5) -- (2,0.5) -- (2,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,0.5);
\draw (5,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (5,3) -- (5,1);
\draw (7,1.5) -- (6,1.5) -- (6,3) -- (7,3) -- (7,1.5);
\draw (0.5,3) -- (0.5,3.8) -- (0,3.8) -- (0.5, 3.3) -- (1,3.8) -- (0.5, 3.8);
\draw (2.5,3) -- (2.5,3.8) -- (2,3.8) -- (2.5, 3.3) -- (3,3.8) -- (2.5, 3.8);
\draw (4.5,3) -- (4.5,3.8) -- (4,3.8) -- (4.5, 3.3) -- (5,3.8) -- (4.5, 3.8);
\draw (6.5,3) -- (6.5,3.8) -- (6,3.8) -- (6.5, 3.3) -- (7,3.8) -- (6.5, 3.8);
\draw[blue] (0.5,3.8) -- (5.5,8.8);
\draw[blue] (2.5,3.8) -- (6.5,7.8);
\draw[blue] (4.5,3.8) -- (7.5,6.8);
\draw[blue] (6.5,3.8) -- (8.5,5.8);
\draw (0.5,0) -- (0.5,-0.5) -- (3.5,-1);
\draw (2.5,0.5) -- (2.5,-0.5) -- (3.5,-1);
\draw (4.5,1) -- (4.5,-0.5) -- (3.5,-1);
\draw (6.5,1.5) -- (6.5,-0.5) -- (3.5,-1);
\draw (3.5,-1) -- (3.5,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate some help, in order to replicate the original sketch of the antenna.

Comment: There are so many numbers in your code. You can read pgfmanual or VisualTikZ to know how to use 'node' to draw your figure